# Is there any way to get engaged users by country

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-insights

Hello I'm using the insights api. But whenever I want engaged users via `/insights/page_engaged_users`, that only gives me the my country's results. Since I'm managing a global page, is there any way to get others by country?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no way in API. Any how you can get following results based on country.

1. Impressions
2. Story Adds
3. Places Checkin
4. Story Tellers
5. Fans